# Request to External Service (S3) takes too much time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, newrelic

I have struggled with this for 2 days now and I just can not figure what I should do. I am using Rails (4.2.3) and Ruby 2.2.1, if that helps in any way.

After installing the new relic gem I have found out that the reason two of my controllers take an enormous time to respond (~17 secs) is due to requests to amazon s3.

Those pages just display 10 records using the ransack gem.

Here is a screenshot for you to see.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

[New Relic external services screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF8bS.png)

Comment: Include a sample of your code that is contacting AWS. If you are making 10 synchronous API requests to S3, then of course it takes 17 seconds to render the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to say exactly, and with 10 records 1.7 seconds per record seems fairly large, maybe you should measure that outside Rails (e.g. request the same URLs direct in a browser).

But generally making 10 sequential requests in a controller is a bad thing. Even if the request was fairly fast, making 10 of them is likely to be many times the slowest thing in that response.

1. You could do this either by spawning 10 threads each to get a record, then joining and rendering the view.
2. Or you could fetch each record asyncronously (non-blocking so all 10 happen at once).
3. Or if you can render the data with AJAX/XHR responses in the page, make the constroller only fetch 1 item and make the app request all 10 seperately (but you will hit the browers max request to a domain limit so wont get a full 10x speedup).
4. If the browser does not need the response immediately, use a background task runner (many Gems) and just tell the browser "its pending". This will avoid holding up your Rails server, but is likely to be even **slower** from a single users perspective.

Unfortunately async support in Ruby/Rails is not great (guess needs more people demanding and contributing). I dont think option 2 is possible at all with the AWS SDK, and you would need to look around for a HTTP client library that is really async to do it at a low level (and not just a thread/fibre wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

External services call like S3 can take time depending upon multiple variables like:

1. Network route b/w your server to S3. Check `traceroute`
2. Latency b/w the servers. Higher `ping` leads to higher time to establish connection.
3. Health at AWS S3 end - if their services are experiencing issues, your service can be affected
4. etc..

It is usually recommended to do tasks like image/file resize/upload in background. Gems like [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) are leveraged to do exactly that.

Comment: The thing is that there is no image manipulation going on on that page. I am resizing etc but on the index page I just display a table  with 10 records being fetched from S3 (no images shown, just the links to files).

Another similar app does not experience such issues with the calls taking too long which makes this more strange.

Comment: are both the apps running on same server?

Comment: No they are on different servers, same region though

Comment: open rails console in both apps and check : `100.times { t = Time.now; call_to_get_s3_link; puts Time.now - t }`

Comment: Also, check traceroute and ping to the S3 url (from your screenshot) from both servers. I have had issue in past where one particular instance in an availability zone was performing better while other was performing bad.

Comment: I just saw they use the same S3 bucket (isn't that odd). Traceroute/ping results are fine. I run what you wrote in the console and the (pdf) urls do take ~14 secs to load.

Comment: probably upload a file in one bucket and try `curl`ing (from both servers) to establish it's network/system issue rather than rails. Time taken should be different.

Comment: I reduced the calls to S3 with substituting with other relevant data. Then I used Ajax to fetch what I needed.